# How do I create an file myfile.html at the top level of the google site www.example.com?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a google website http://www.example.com.
How do I create the file [http://www.example.com/myfile.html](http://www.example.com/myfile.html%C2%A0)  ?

I was told to "simply create a file at http://www.example.com/myfile.html (at the top level of the site), with specific contents."  Not so simple for me....

The website was acquired on sites.google.com
It is on a domain I own managed on enom.
I have tried adding a page to the website.
I have tried inserting myfile.html in the website.
I have tried inserting the contents of myfile.html in the website.

Comment: Do u have FTP or something same?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a Google website, but I assume you have a website hosted on one of the Google services? Tell us more about how do you host your website.

Comment: Please provide some more information about your problem and show us what you've tried so far

Comment: What service are you using?